# Laravel Collective SSH results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am performing SSH in Laravel whereby I connect to another server and download a file.  I am using Laravel Collective https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/ssh

So, the suggested way to do this is something like this

```
$result = \SSH::into('scripts')->get('/srv/somelocation/'.$fileName, $path);

if($result) {
   return $path;
} else {
    return 401;
}
```

Now that successfully downloads the file and moves it to my local server.  However, I am always returned 401 because $result seems to be Null.

I cant find much or getting the result back from the SSH.  I have also tried

```
$result = \SSH::into('scripts')->get('/srv/somelocation/'.$fileName, $path, function($line){
    dd( $line.PHP_EOL);
});
```

But that never gets into the inner function.

Is there any way I can get the result back from the SSH?  I just want to handle it properly if there is an error.

Thanks

Comment: better use PHPSecLib, use the Net2 class and SSH, you will get interactive result as you get in the console and you can build console on web too. I have used phpseclib and each time when i fire any ssh command or any thing i get exact result. I have used with laravel 5.3 and 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on `$result` to give you `true` / `false` / error, you can check if the file was downloaded successfully in another way:

```
// download the file
$result = \SSH::into('scripts')->get('/srv/somelocation/'.$fileName, $path);

// see if downloaded file exists
if ( file_exists($path) ) {
  return $path;
} else {
  return 401;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to pass file name also like this in get and put method:

```
$fileName = "example.txt";

$get = \SSH::into('scripts')->get('/remote/somelocation/'.$fileName, base_path($fileName));
```

in set method

```
$set = \SSH::into('scripts')->set(base_path($fileName),'/remote/location/'.$fileName);
```

in list

```
$command = SSH::into('scripts')->run(['ls -lsa'],function($output) {
    dd($output);
});
```